# python3 print to string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, stringio

Using Python 3, I have a console application that I am porting to a GUI. The code has a bunch of print statements, something like this:

`print(f1(), f2(), f3(), sep=getsep(), end=getend())`

I would like to convert these calls into something like:

`GuiPrintLine(f1(), f2(), f3(), sep=getsep(), end=getend())`

where each line is eventually rendered using some (undefined) GUI framework.

This is easy to do if I can convert the arguments to print into to the string that print would normally produce without the side-effect of actually printing to sysout. In other words, I need a function like this:

```
s = print_to_string(*args, **kwargs)
```

How do I format a set of parameters to print(...) into a single string that produces the same output as print() would produce?

I realize I could emulate print by concatenating all the args with sep and ends, but I would prefer to use a built-in solution if there is one.

Using print and redirecting sysout is not attractive since it requires modifying the global state of the app and sysout might be used for other diagnostics at the same time.

It seems like this should be trivial in Python, so maybe I'm just missing something obvious.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand 100%, but does `''.join(args)` achieve what you need?

Comment: Sort of, but I don't want to assume anything about the contents or existence of sep/end.  I've been thinking something like this might work: ```kwargs['sep'].join(*args, kwargs[end])```, but it is complicated by dealing with the possible absence of sep/end.

Comment: What would be the difference between `print` and `GuiPrintLine`?

Comment: `sep.join(args) + end` does seem like the best solution.

Comment: @bjskistad - GuiPrintLine doesn't actually output the text to sysout.  It renders it graphically in some (undefined) way - using tkinter, pygame, whatever...

Comment: It's kinda hard for the answerer to answer the question if he/she doesn't know exactly what you want `GuiPrintLine` to do. Do you want it to create a curses application? Create a HTTP server and print HTML?

Comment: @bjskistad - I do not need help with the final output of the string. I already know how to handle that part.  My question is entirely about getting a series of arguments that would normally go to print formatted into a single string.

Comment: So you want them formatted as separate strings?

Comment: I guess that's what's unclear, what are you trying to get done here if you say you don't actually want the output that print would produce?

Comment: @pvg - I want exactly the output that print would produce, *but as a string*, not as output on stdout.

Comment: Ah i see. StringIO is what you want.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Found the answer via string io.  With this I don't have to emulate Print's handling of sep/end or even check for existence.

```
import io

def print_to_string(*args, **kwargs):
    output = io.StringIO()
    print(*args, file=output, **kwargs)
    contents = output.getvalue()
    output.close()
    return contents
```

Comment: I was just about to suggest that.  You can clear a StringIO object for reuse with the .seek(0) and .truncate() methods.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, this will add a newline to the end of the string; to avoid that, the `end` parameter should be forwarded to `print`.

Comment: @entonio, I believe end is forwarded to print via  **kwargs, is it not?

Comment: Isn't it better to use `with io.StringIO() as output:` syntax ? It is shorter, clearer, and safer IMHO.

Comment: @user36313 - more concise perhaps, how "safer"?

Answer (score 2):

My solution :

```
def print_to_string(*args, **kwargs):
    newstr = ""
    for a in args:
        newstr+=str(a)+' '
    return newstr
```